# My search is not working in yii2 ,i have to try to find the solution but fails

Tags: yii2

I want to search my data but the search is not working. I can't understand what's going wrong? please help to fix it... here is the code

### payable controller

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Payable;
use app\models\PayableSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * PayableController implements the CRUD actions for Payable model.
 */
class PayableController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Payable models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PayableSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Payable model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Payable model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Payable();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Payable model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Payable model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Payable model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Payable the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Payable::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

### **PaybleSearch**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Payable;

/**
 * PayableSearch represents the model behind the search form of `app\models\Payable`.
 */
class PayableSearch extends Payable
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'consumer_id', 'total_months_conservancy', 'water_arrears', 'conservancy_amount', 'total_water_and_conservancy_amount', 'tinure', 'dues_amount', 'per_month_charges', 'no_of_months', 'total_amount_of_current_months', 'advanced_pay', 'arrears', 'arrears_period', 'total_bill', 'after_due_date_charges', 'total_after_due_date', 'balance_arears', 'water_charges_per_month', 'conservancy_charges_per_month', 'four_months_water_charges', 'four_months_conservancy_charges'], 'integer'],
            [['water_remarks', 'remarks', 'billing_months', 'issue_date', 'due_date'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Bill::find()->where('status=0');
        // echo"<pre>";
        // print_r($query);
        // exit();
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'consumer_id' => $this->consumer_id,
            'total_months_conservancy' => $this->total_months_conservancy,
            'water_arrears' => $this->water_arrears,
            'conservancy_amount' => $this->conservancy_amount,
            'total_water_and_conservancy_amount' => $this->total_water_and_conservancy_amount,
            'tinure' => $this->tinure,
            'dues_amount' => $this->dues_amount,
            'per_month_charges' => $this->per_month_charges,
            'no_of_months' => $this->no_of_months,
            'total_amount_of_current_months' => $this->total_amount_of_current_months,
            'advanced_pay' => $this->advanced_pay,
            'arrears' => $this->arrears,
            'arrears_period' => $this->arrears_period,
            'total_bill' => $this->total_bill,
            'after_due_date_charges' => $this->after_due_date_charges,
            'total_after_due_date' => $this->total_after_due_date,
            'balance_arears' => $this->balance_arears,
            'water_charges_per_month' => $this->water_charges_per_month,
            'conservancy_charges_per_month' => $this->conservancy_charges_per_month,
            'four_months_water_charges' => $this->four_months_water_charges,
            'four_months_conservancy_charges' => $this->four_months_conservancy_charges,
            'issue_date' => $this->issue_date,
            'due_date' => $this->due_date,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'water_remarks', $this->water_remarks])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'remarks', $this->remarks])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'billing_months', $this->billing_months]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

### **Payable Model**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "payable".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $consumer_id
 * @property int $total_months_conservancy
 * @property int $water_arrears
 * @property string $water_remarks
 * @property int $conservancy_amount
 * @property int $total_water_and_conservancy_amount
 * @property int $tinure
 * @property int $dues_amount
 * @property int $per_month_charges
 * @property int $no_of_months
 * @property int $total_amount_of_current_months
 * @property int $advanced_pay
 * @property int $arrears
 * @property int $arrears_period
 * @property int $total_bill
 * @property int $after_due_date_charges
 * @property int $total_after_due_date
 * @property int $balance_arears
 * @property string $remarks
 * @property int $water_charges_per_month
 * @property int $conservancy_charges_per_month
 * @property int $four_months_water_charges
 * @property int $four_months_conservancy_charges
 * @property string $billing_months
 * @property string $issue_date
 * @property string $due_date
 */
class Payable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'payable';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['consumer_id', 'total_months_conservancy', 'water_arrears', 'water_remarks', 'conservancy_amount', 'total_water_and_conservancy_amount', 'tinure', 'dues_amount', 'per_month_charges', 'no_of_months', 'total_amount_of_current_months', 'advanced_pay', 'arrears', 'arrears_period', 'total_bill', 'after_due_date_charges', 'total_after_due_date', 'balance_arears', 'remarks', 'water_charges_per_month', 'conservancy_charges_per_month', 'four_months_water_charges', 'four_months_conservancy_charges', 'billing_months', 'issue_date', 'due_date'], 'required'],
            [['consumer_id', 'total_months_conservancy', 'water_arrears', 'conservancy_amount', 'total_water_and_conservancy_amount', 'tinure', 'dues_amount', 'per_month_charges', 'no_of_months', 'total_amount_of_current_months', 'advanced_pay', 'arrears', 'arrears_period', 'total_bill', 'after_due_date_charges', 'total_after_due_date', 'balance_arears', 'water_charges_per_month', 'conservancy_charges_per_month', 'four_months_water_charges', 'four_months_conservancy_charges'], 'integer'],
            [['issue_date', 'due_date'], 'safe'],
            [['water_remarks'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
            [['remarks'], 'string', 'max' => 350],
            [['billing_months'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'consumer_id' => 'Consumer ID',
            'total_months_conservancy' => 'Total Months Conservancy',
            'water_arrears' => 'Water Arrears',
            'water_remarks' => 'Water Remarks',
            'conservancy_amount' => 'Conservancy Amount',
            'total_water_and_conservancy_amount' => 'Total Water And Conservancy Amount',
            'tinure' => 'Tinure',
            'dues_amount' => 'Dues Amount',
            'per_month_charges' => 'Per Month Charges',
            'no_of_months' => 'No Of Months',
            'total_amount_of_current_months' => 'Total Amount Of Current Months',
            'advanced_pay' => 'Advanced Pay',
            'arrears' => 'Arrears',
            'arrears_period' => 'Arrears Period',
            'total_bill' => 'Total Bill',
            'after_due_date_charges' => 'After Due Date Charges',
            'total_after_due_date' => 'Total After Due Date',
            'balance_arears' => 'Balance Arears',
            'remarks' => 'Remarks',
            'water_charges_per_month' => 'Water Charges Per Month',
            'conservancy_charges_per_month' => 'Conservancy Charges Per Month',
            'four_months_water_charges' => 'Four Months Water Charges',
            'four_months_conservancy_charges' => 'Four Months Conservancy Charges',
            'billing_months' => 'Billing Months',
            'issue_date' => 'Issue Date',
            'due_date' => 'Due Date',
        ];
    }

     public function getconsumerId()
                { 
                    return $this->hasOne(Plot::className(),['id' => 'consumer_id']);
                }

}
```

### View.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Payable */

$this->title = $model->id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Payables', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
\yii\web\YiiAsset::register($this);
?>
<div class="payable-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'consumer_id',
            'total_months_conservancy',
            'water_arrears',
            'water_remarks',
            'conservancy_amount',
            'total_water_and_conservancy_amount',
            'tinure',
            'dues_amount',
            'per_month_charges',
            'no_of_months',
            'total_amount_of_current_months',
            'advanced_pay',
            'arrears',
            'arrears_period',
            'total_bill',
            'after_due_date_charges',
            'total_after_due_date',
            'balance_arears',
            'remarks',
            'water_charges_per_month',
            'conservancy_charges_per_month',
            'four_months_water_charges',
            'four_months_conservancy_charges',
            'billing_months',
            'issue_date',
            'due_date',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

### Index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\PayableSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Payables';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="payable-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Payable', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //  
            
            'id',
            [    'header'=> 'Consumer Name',
                'attribute'=>'consumer_id',
                'value'=>'consumerId.allottee_name',
            ],
            // 'total_months_conservancy',
            // 'water_arrears',
            // 'water_remarks',
            // 'conservancy_amount',
            //'total_water_and_conservancy_amount',
            //'tinure',
            //'dues_amount',
            //'per_month_charges',
            //'no_of_months',
            //'total_amount_of_current_months',
            //'advanced_pay',
            'arrears',
            //'arrears_period',
            'total_bill',
            //'after_due_date_charges',
            'total_after_due_date',
            //'balance_arears',
            //'remarks',
            //'water_charges_per_month',
            //'conservancy_charges_per_month',
            //'four_months_water_charges',
            //'four_months_conservancy_charges',
            'billing_months',
            //'issue_date',
            'due_date',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>
```

I want to make a search but the search is not working. I tried but fails. I could not found any error.please help me in finding the issue

Comment: post your `view` form

Comment: Serghei kindly check it again

Comment: How it's behave right now? after first load does it show records? what happen when you type `consumer_id` or `id`? does it returns exact record?

Comment: Serghei it shows records but when i want to search and type ' id ' or 'consumer id' nothing happens.it remains same

Comment: Does your `url` change after you submit? it should be pretty long `url`

Comment: try to enter some `id` and then `hit enter`.

Comment: I entered the id but neither the page load nor the search work, it behaves like nothing happened

Comment: Check your browser debug console, and jquery for any errors.

Comment: I  check it but no error found

Comment: Where are you entering the search parameters? In the code you posted the `search.php` file is not getting rendered, is commented out. `// echo...`