# Yii2 grid view search not working ,i cannot understand the error

Tags: gridview, yii2

### Category Model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "category".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $category_name
 * @property string $water_bill
 * @property string $conservancy
 * @property int|null $siz_width
 * @property int|null $siz_height
 * @property int|null $created_by
 * @property string|null $created_on
 * @property int|null $updated_by
 * @property string|null $updated_on
 */
class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'category';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['category_name',  'conservancy'], 'required'],
            [['siz_width', 'siz_height', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
            [['created_on', 'updated_on'], 'safe'],
            [['category_name', 'conservancy'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'category_name' => 'Category Name',
            
            'conservancy' => 'Conservancy',
            'siz_width' => 'Size Width',
            'siz_height' => 'Size Height',
            'un.username' => 'Created By',
            'created_on' => 'Created On',
            'name.username' => 'Updated By',
            'updated_on' => 'Updated On',
        ];
    }

                public function getname()
                {
                    return $this->hasOne(User::className(),['id' => 'updated_by']);
                }

                 public function getun()
                {
                    return $this->hasOne(User::className(),['id' => 'created_by']);
                }

}
```

### CategorySearch

```
#
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Category;

/**
 * CategorySearch represents the model behind the search form of `app\models\Category`.
 */
class CategorySearch extends Category
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'siz_width', 'siz_height', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
            [['category_name',  'conservancy', 'created_on', 'updated_on'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Category::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'siz_width' => $this->siz_width,
            'siz_height' => $this->siz_height,
            'created_by' => $this->created_by,
            'created_on' => $this->created_on,
            'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
            'updated_on' => $this->updated_on,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'category_name', $this->category_name])
            
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'conservancy', $this->conservancy]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

### Index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\CategorySearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Categories');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="category-index">


    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <div class="card-header py-3 panel" style="">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', '+ Add Category'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>

        </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="padding:20px; border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; ">

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'summary' => "",
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'id',

           [
             'attribute'=> 'category_name',
             'value'=> 'category_name',
         ],
         
            'siz_width',
            'siz_height',
            'conservancy',
            //'created_by',
            //'created_on',
            //'updated_by',
            //'updated_on',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header'=>'Action',
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '80'],
            
            'template' => '{View}{Update}{Delete}',

            'buttons'=> [
                'Delete' => function ($url,$model,$key){
                    return html::a('<i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:16px;color:#F05550 "></i>' ,url::to(['/category/delete?id='.$model->id]));
                },
                'View' => function ($url,$model,$key){
                    return html::a('<i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:16px;color:#00cc66"></i>' ,url::to(['/category/view?id='.$model->id]));
                },
                'Update' => function ($url,$model,$key){
                    return html::a('<i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:16px;color:#4A94D2"></i>',url::to(['/category/update?id='.$model->id]));
                }
            ]
        ],
        ],
    ]); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

### View.php

```
[<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Category */

$this->title = $model->category_name;
$this->params\['breadcrumbs'\]\[\] = \['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Categories'), 'url' => \['index'\]\];
$this->params\['breadcrumbs'\]\[\] = $this->title;
\yii\web\YiiAsset::register($this);
?>
<div class="category-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Update'), \['update', 'id' => $model->id\], \['class' => 'btn btn-primary'\]) ?>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Delete'), \['delete', 'id' => $model->id\], \[
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => \[
                'confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
                'method' => 'post',
            \],
        \]) ?>
    </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget(\[
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => \[
          
            'category_name',
            
            
            'siz_width',
            'siz_height',
            'conservancy',
            // 'created_by',
            'un.username',
            'created_on',
            'name.username',
            // 'un.username',
            'updated_on',
        \],
    \]) ?>

</div>]
```

### Controller

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Category;
use app\models\CategorySearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use app\models\User;

/**
 * CategoryController implements the CRUD actions for Category model.
 */
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class'=>AccessControl::classname(),
                'only'=>['create'],
                'rules' =>[
                [

                    'allow'=>true,
                    'roles'=>['@']
                ],
            ]
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Category models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CategorySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Category model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Category model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Category();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
            $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->created_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if($model->validate()){
                if($model->save()){
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }else{

                }
            }
        }
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Updates an existing Category model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            $model->updated_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            $model->updated_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if($model->validate()){
         if($model->save()) {
             
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }else{

                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Category model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Category model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Category the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Category::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }

}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTk4t.png)

I am new to yii2.I want to search my data but My search is not working when I search 'size width', 'size height' nothing happens. Help me to solve this problem.I cannot find what's going wrong with my code.What should i have to do to make it working?I want to search my data but the search is not working. I can't understand what's going wrong? please help to fix it... here is the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My search is not working in yii2 ,i have to try to find the solution but fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849036/my-search-is-not-working-in-yii2-i-have-to-try-to-find-the-solution-but-fails)

Comment: Insane skull no its not anwser of my question

Comment: Can you show your `Action` code? Also after the `$this->validate()` try adding `print_r($this->errors);` to see if there's any attribute errors.

Comment: Show your controller code

Comment: donot post multiple questions for the same problem

Comment: Farshid check the controller code

Comment: This is my action code:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CategorySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }